# ¿Qué quiere decir "salir vaciado" en Colombia?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, coloquialismos, colombia

Leo el titular en el periódico colombiano El Espectador:

> [Fiscalía **salió vaciada** por querer cerrar caso contra prima del "Ñoño" Elías](https://www.elespectador.com/noticias/judicial/la-vaciada-la-fiscalia-por-querer-cerrar-el-caso-contra-la-prima-del-nono-elias-articulo-877155)
>
> El regaño vino del Tribunal Superior de Bogotá, que rechazó la petición del organismo investigador de precluir el proceso de Básima Elías. (...) Para la Sala Penal del Tribunal Superior de Bogotá es inadmisible que la Fiscalía considere que (...) es legal.

Por lo que parece que al decir *salir vaciada* está diciendo que una instancia reprende una acción de otra.

Mirando en el DLE veo solamente esta opción:

> [**vaciar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bEU81MJ)
>   `De vacío.`
>
> 9. tr. Guat. reprender.

Y luego el Diccionario de americanismos indica, entre muchas otras acepciones:

> [**vaciar(se)**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=n2DsXxvTcx0AbUhRuAb)
>
> IV.   1.  tr. Gu, Pa, Co. Reprender a alguien. pop. ◆ retacar.
>
> V.    1.  intr. prnl. Co. Perder su forma una prenda como consecuencia del uso.

Es decir, la entrada IV va en la línea de lo dicho por el DLE, pero incluyendo ya a Colombia (y Panamá) en el listado de países donde se usa y marcándolo como de uso popular.

Así y todo, veo que en el titular de la noticia que mencionaba habla de *salir vaciado*, por lo que me surge la duda de si existe también esta construcción como expresión.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En Colombia *una vaciada* es un regaño o una reprimenda mediante un largo discurso. Es un sinónimo de *cantaleta*

En el caso del ejemplo alguien intenta dejar en libertad a un criminal y, en consecuencia (salió), recibe como respuesta del Tribunal un largo discurso regañándolo (vaciada) por su estúpido intento.

En Colombia es común oír algo como:

> - Juan llegó tarde al trabajo y el jefe le **metió una vaciada.**
> - Juan llegó tarde al trabajo y el jefe lo *regañó por más de 10 minutos*

o

> - Juan se **ganó una vaciada** por llegar tarde al trabajo
> - Juan se *hizo acreedor a una larga reprimenda* por llegar tarde al trabajo.

o

> - La esposa de Juan es muy brava y lo **vive vaciando.**
> - La esposa de Juan es muy brava y lo *mantiene a punta de cantaleta*
> - La esposa de Juan es muy brava y *permanentemente lo regaña por cualquier cosa*.

o

> - Juan le pidió dinero a su padre y **salió vaciado** por perder el trabajo por no madrugar
> - Juan le pidió dinero a su padre y en lugar de darle dinero su padre *le dió un largo discurso* para que madrugara y no perdiera el trabajo.-

Comment: Fantástico, gracias Diego! De paso también me descubriste la palabra *cantaleta*.

Comment: De paso aclaro que puede haber una pequeña diferencia entre _cantaleta_ y _vaciada_ donde _vaciada_ puede incluir palabras **insultantes** ([PG-13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America_film_rating_system#MPAA_film_ratings)) mientras que _cantaleta_ es normalmente [PG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America_film_rating_system#MPAA_film_ratings)